# Using #define for printf, does it effect on speed

Tags: c++, c

I am using

```
#define printInt(x)  printf ("%d",x)
```

In `main()`

I can use it like this:

```
int var=10;
printInt (var);
```

Which is easier to use than typing

```
printf ("%d",var);
```

Will using my own `#define` for printing an `int`, `float` etc make my program slower?

Comment: Using a macro than typing the code doesn't slow down your program. Because your preprocessor will replace your macro with it's contents. The resulting code should be the same.

Comment: The macro may waste more time during debugging and maintenance.  It is a *false function*; it looks like a function but is a macro.  I strongly recommend banning this kind of practice.  Are you really saving a great amount of type (hint: copy and paste is a better technique), or take a keyboarding class.

Comment: What you are doing is one of those things that look like a great idea, but are not. In six months, %d in a format string will look absolutely fine to you.

Answer (score 5):

No this will not effect the speed. The macro is expanded during pre-processing so that in every instance that you use `printInt(myInt)` what is actually passed to the compiler will be `printf("%d", myInt)`. So I think the binary output would be identical either way.

Comment: The macro only saves typing time; which could be wasted by a trip to the coffee machine or restroom.  Take a keyboarding class.

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't affect the speed of your program.

The `#define` instructions are processed by the preprocessor before your program is compiled.

For example the call

```
printInt(var);
```

is replaced with

```
printf ("%d",var);
```

by the preprocessor.

Therefore the compiler can't determine if a `#define` was used or not. In both cases it leads to the **same** code (and the same program). Thats the reason why it isn't possible that both programs differ in their speed.

---

**EDIT:** If you use a lot of `#defines` in your program, it is possible that the speed of the proprocessing step decreases. But in most cases this should be no problem.